# Can't see cookie

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have been banging my head against the wall for days with a cookie problem.

I have 3 files which I have simplified to

`cookiew.php` which writes the cookie and is at http://clickme9.com/s/cookiew.php

```
<?php
setcookie('test', '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 90);
?>
cookie set<br>
```

`test.html` which is at http://clickme9.com/s/test.html

```
<img src="http://clickme9.com/s/cookier.php" width='1' height='1' />
cookie written to file<br>
```

`cookier.php` which is at http://clickme9.com/s/cookier.php

```
<?php
$s = "cookie not set";
if ($_COOKIE['test']){
  $s = $_COOKIE['test'];
  setcookie('test', '', time()-3600);  
}

file_put_contents('cookie.log', $s);
?>
```

under this condition it works fine and 1 gets written to http://clickme9.com/s/cookie.log

but if I move the test.html file to another domain it does not work.
The `cookier.php` is still on the same domain as the `cookiew.php` so should work
and does work fine with other hit or click counters so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Is cookie.log writable?

Comment: yes since it works fine if on same domain

Comment: What does var_dump($_COOKIE) tell you?

Comment: since it is being run by loading an image you would not be able to see anything.

Comment: and when off domain it writes cookie not set to the file fine

Answer (score 0):

**Try this set a cookie following way :**

```
setcookie ('test', '1', time()+ 60 * 60 * 24 * 90, '/', NULL, 0 );
```

Comment: I had already tried using the other parameters but it had no effect. I tried again with same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine in chrome and firefox but does not work in IE8 and IE11 (only IE versions tested).
That is a little scary!